# how to make text responsive in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the text displayed in my application to adjust the screen size. whether by using the default textTheme will produce responsive text?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674962/how-to-make-text-as-big-as-the-width-allows-in-flutter) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package, for responsive font you can use like this

```
 Text(
     '16sp, will not change with the system.',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.sp, // this will make font responsive
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: can only using textTheme as below make text responsive?
Text(
             'Text with a background color',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
           ),

Comment: I didn't have any idea so I've checked with two different devices and I personally didn't find much different. Both devices it looks same.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have "responsive text" you can access the size of the screen with this

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

and then you have the ability to change the size of the text by doing

```
Center(
    child: Text(
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: size.width * 0.005, //play arround with this number to get the size you want
            ),
         ),
      ),
```

Comment: can only using textTheme as below make text responsive?
Text(
             'Text with a background color',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
           ),

Answer (score 0):

you can make text responsive with the help of screen width.

And you should try

```
 fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 500 ?60 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 300 ?40:30,
```

The above statement means that, when your screen width is greater than 500 then show textsize  **60** if less than **300**, then show textsize **30** else between **500 and 300** shows textsize **40**

Comment: can only using textTheme as below make text responsive?
Text(
             'Text with a background color',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
           ),

Comment: Please edit your questions and explain what you want exactly - Thanks. The text Responsive means its size fit every screen size.